# RHEL 7 repository glibc yum installation

Tags: redhat, rhel7, glibc

I have a problem to install glibc.i686 package from RHEL 7 repository. I doesn't understand why only glibc.i686 package from RHEL 6 repository is avialable:

```
sudo yum list glibc*

> **Installed Packages**
**glibc.x86_64                                                                                    2.17-106.el7_2.4**                                                                              @rhel-x86_64-server-7
glibc-common.x86_64                                                                             2.17-106.el7_2.4                                                                              @rhel-x86_64-server-7
**Available Packages**
**glibc.i686                                                                                      2.12-1.209.el6_9.2**                                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-6 
glibc-devel.i686                                                                                2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-6 
glibc-devel.x86_64                                                                              2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-6 
glibc-headers.x86_64                                                                            2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-6 
glibc-utils.x86_64                                                                              2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                                                                            rhel-x86_64-server-6
```

In other servers (cloned VMs) I have no problem to install through yum -y glibc.i686 and the version was same as glibc.x86_64

```
> **glibc.i686**                                                                                    **2.17-157.el7_3.1**                                                                              @rhel-x86_64-server-7
**glibc.x86_64                                                                                    2.17-157.el7_3.1**                                                                              @rhel-x86_64-server-7
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Also:

- yum clean all I have already done. It didn't help.
- cat /etc/redhat-release Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
- repolist: *epel/x86_64 , pgdg95/7Server/x86_64, rhel-x86_64-server-6, vmware-tools

Comment: Could you provide: "cat /etc/redhat-release", "yum repolist", and also try "yum clean all" and then your "yum list" command?

Comment: - `yum clean all` I have already done. It didn't help.
- `cat /etc/redhat-release`
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Comment: - reposlist: 
`*epel/x86_64 , pgdg95/7Server/x86_64, rhel-x86_64-server-6, vmware-tools`

Comment: That's the problem, the RHEL7 repositories are not configured but the RHEL6 one is (`rhel-x86_64-server-6`). Is this attached to RHN? Have you checked what subscription and license it has?

Comment: I don't think so, this is from another server, almost same setup as the problematic ones (clone), -repolist `*epel/x86_64, rhel-x86_64-server-6, vmware-tools` But no issues with RHEL6/RHEL7 glibc. Correctly installed glibc.i686 from RHEL7 repository.

Comment: Repolist shows that it's configured to use the RHEL 6 repositories. You won't find RHEL 7 packages in RHEL 6 repositories.

Comment: Ok than how to configure RHEL 7 repository? I found couple of links how to configure local RHEL 7  repository (anyway I need a mirror for RHEL 7.2), but is there some *.repo file so than I can add repo through for example `yum-config-manager --add-repo http://www.example.com/example.repo`